# Force gif reload in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've a modal component with 3 steps. In the first step I've a gif with no loop (in other words, the gif is NOT a infinite gif). When I open the modal and when I go back to the first step I want the gif to restart the animation and loop just one time.

**My problem is**: when I first show the gif, the browser download the gif and the gif works fine, but after that the browser get the gif from cache and doesn't start again. So when I close the modal and open again or I go back to the first step again, it's like I've a image and not a gif.

**Restrictions:** I can't download the gif more than one time, so I can't put  `?a=${Math.random()` to force the gif to loop again.

**What I tried:**

1) I tried to put src empty in the `img` tag when I'm not in the first step and when the modal is not opened. And when I'm in the first step and the modal is opened I put the gif in the src of the `img` tag

2) I tried to do the same thing as the 1 attempt but with another gif

3) I tried to do the same as attempt 1 and 2 in the modal component and pass the src to the step children component

4) I tried to remove the `img` tag out of the DOM when I'm not in the first step and the modal is not opened

**My simplified components:**

```
export class Modal extends React.PureComponent {
  state = { step: FIRST_STEP }

  render() {
    {currentStep === FIRST_STEP && this.renderFirstStep()}
    {currentStep === SECOND_STEP && this.renderSecondStep()}
  }

  renderFirstStep() {
    return <FirstStep />
  }
}

export class FirstStep extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <img src={gif} alt='gif' />
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can restart a non-infinite gif by clearing the image src and then re-setting it.

the way to do this in reactJS is by using component state and a zero length timeout to push to next tick

```js
class ReloadableGif extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      gif: 'http://insightgraphicdesign.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/coke-responsive-logo.gif',
      loaded: 'http://insightgraphicdesign.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/coke-responsive-logo.gif'
    }
  }
  
  reloadGif = () => {
    this.setState({loaded: ''})
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({loaded: this.state.gif})
    }, 0)
  }
  
  render(){
    return <div>
      <img src={this.state.loaded} />
      <button onClick={this.reloadGif}>Replay Animation</button>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReloadableGif />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<main id="react">
http://insightgraphicdesign.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/coke-responsive-logo.gif
</main>
```

Comment: It did work nicely, however, I can see a kind of "jump" between the two loaded images. Like for 0.5s there is a blank image. It's a bit annoying, anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: @LukyVj either get an actual repeating gif, or get a static image of the first frame, and use that as the source between loops

Comment: It works nicely in class. I don't get it why it doesn't work in functionl component.

Answer (score 0):

```
import welcomeGif from 'modules/Onboarding/assets/welcomeGif.gif'

export class FirstStep extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()

    this.src = welcomeGif
  }

  render() {
    if (this.gif)
      this.gif.src = this.src

    return(
      <img
        src={this.src}
        alt='welcomeGif'
        ref={input => this.gif = input}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation for a gif shown inside a div. If the div is hidden, then the gif is set to an empty string. This makes sure the gif is animated each time the div is shown.

```
import path1 from '../myGif.gif'
renderGif(show) {
    //set myGif and styleToDisplay for the case where
    //the div will be shown
    let myGif = path1
    var styleToDisplay = {
        position:"absolute",
    }

    //if div will not be shown, set div to hidden and 
    //myGif=""
    if (!show) {
        myGif = ""
        styleToDisplay = {display: "none"}
    }

    //instead of just returning null here when div 
    //is not shown, return a hidden div where myGif = ""
    return(
        <div
            onClick={this.toggleShow}
            style={styleToDisplay}>

            <img src={myGif} width="250px" height="250px"/>
        </div>
    );
}


toggleShow = () => {
    let t = this.state.show
    this.setState({
        show: !t,
    })
}

//call this function from another component 
//or wherever you want to show the gif
showGif () => {
    this.setState({
        show: true,
    })
}

//main render function
render() {
    return (
        {this.renderGif(this.state.show}
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this will help, but you can use this package to add loopback https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-typing-animation

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this package isn't for my use case :/