# I am trying to restart a GIF animation in a React using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, animated-gif

I have found similar questions with answers I have tried to modify I looked at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892134/force-gif-reload-in-react/48892561) in particular. The goal here is to get the GIF to restart every time  this component is shown. My sample code has been through an iteration or two, and this is where it is as of now.

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import NavMenu from '../components/NavMenu'
import {Box, Typography} from '@mui/material'
import backgroundImage from '../assets/images/world-bg.png'
import Logo from '../assets/images/chr-logo-white@2x.png'
import landscape from '../assets/gifs/why-we-exist_1test.gif'
import { Gif } from "@mui/icons-material";


const Exist = () => {

    const [gif, setGif] =useState('')

    const reloadGif = () => {
        setGif('')
        setTimeout(() => {
          setGif(landscape)
        }, 0)
      }

    useEffect(() => {
       reloadGif()
        return () => {
            setGif('')
        }
    },[]
    )

    const styles ={
        introContainer:{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100vw',
            backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignContent: 'center',
            color:'white',
            textAlign:'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignContent:'center',
            flexShrink:0
        }
    }

    return (
        <Box sx = {styles.introContainer}>
            <NavMenu />
            <Box >
              {gif !== '' && <img src={gif} alt="Logo"></img>}
            </Box>
            <Footer logo={false} back={'intro'} next={"home"}/>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default Exist;
```

I was hoping that my useEffect would clear the image src and then set it again forcing a re-render. The problem I am seeing is that with the empty dependency array it won't trigger a re-render, but without it, I get constant re-renders, but with the GIF still only playing once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is most likely that you don't have a clear way to retrigger the use effect to make the Gif reload.

There are several solutions to this, but it depends on how you implemented the logic to show and not show your component.

As you already realized a useEffect with an empty dependency array is triggered whenever the component is put on the screen.

As a solution you need to check out how you are currently rendering your component with the gif to the screen. You have to make sure it is newly added to the DOM, whenever you want to play the gif.

As a side note: There is no need for the return function in your useEffect.

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [showChildComponent, setShowChildComponent] = useState(true)


  return (
 <>
   <button onClick={() => {setShowChildComponent(!showChildComponent)}}>
    Click me to show or hide the child component
   </button>
   { showChildComponent && <ChildComponent /> }
 </>
  )
}

const ChildComponent = () => {
   const [gif, setGif] =useState('')

const reloadGif = () => {
    setGif('')
    setTimeout(() => {
      setGif(landscape)
    }, 0)
  }

useEffect(() => {
   reloadGif()
  },[]
)

 return (<img src={gif} alt="Logo"></img>) 
}
```

You can also retrigger a useEffect with the help of a prop / state.
The following useEffect would be retriggered everytime your showGif state now changes, which you could set whenever you want to play your gif.

```
   const [retriggerGif, setRetriggerGif] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
       reloadGif()
    },[retriggerGif]
    )
```

#### In case you can not mount / unmount your component

In the comments you mentioned you use a hash based router and only wrap your component in a RouterLink.

In this case you could make your useEffect depend on the hash of your router and always rerun of the hash changes:

This of course depends on what router you are using but there is always a way to get the currently active path and hash somehow.

In react-router you e.g. can get the `history` object through the `useHistory()` hook like this:

```
const history = useHistory() 

useEffect(() => { 
    // check that you are at the correct hash 
    if(history.hash === 'header') { 
        reloadGif() 
    } 
}, [history])
```

Comment: Thank you, the component showing the GIF is a "page" that is routed to, so no real logic there to control the showing of the component, just a Router Link. This will be the case for a few pages that will be using some default navigation to get to them.  I can change these Links to button and keep routing handled by state, however that seems messy and less elegant

Comment: I was using a return in my useEffect to act as an unmount, hoping that after navigating away I could change the source so it would have to update the source on mount. And one more point of clarification, it is using Hash Router, not Dom. So, 

    `<Router forceRefresh={true}>`

will not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Carolin's answer as a starting point. I was able to come up with a solution, still feels hacky but it works.

```
import {useEffect} from "react"
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import NavMenu from '../components/NavMenu'
import {Box} from '@mui/material'
import backgroundImage from '../assets/images/world-bg.png'
import landscape from '../assets/gifs/why-we-exist_1test.gif'




const Exist = ({viewCount, handleView}) => {


useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
     return handleView(viewCount + 1)
    }
},[])

const styles ={
    introContainer:{
        height: '100%',
        width: '100vw',
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignContent: 'center',
        color:'white',
        textAlign:'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent:'center',
        flexShrink:0
    }
}

return (
    <Box sx = {styles.introContainer}>
        <NavMenu />
        <Box >
        {viewCount %2 === 0 && <img src={landscape + "?=" + Date.now()} alt="Logo"></img>}
        {viewCount %2 !== 0 && <img src={landscape + "?=" + Date.now()} alt="Logo"></img>}
        </Box>
        <Footer logo={false} back={'intro'} next={"home"}/>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Exist;
```

where viewCount and handleView are `const [count, setCount]=useState(0)` props from parent component

Comment: I just extended my answer to show a different solution that could work with your Hash Router setup. Maybe it helps to make yours a bit less hacky.

Comment: But maybe I can understand your usecase even better if you add the code where you then add your <Exist/> component in your application. (whereever you wrap it with the RouterLink.)